# How to change Bootstrap 4 Navbar link color for sign-up button only?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I've added signup class to the one nav item and trying to change its link color into white. But whatever I tried none of them changed its link color. It stays default one all the time. Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  bg-faded ">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="../assets/images/close.png" class="img-fluid" style="width:50px; height:50px" alt="">
  </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
          >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
      >
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home" >Item 1</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item signin">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/sign-in" >Sign in</a>
      </li>

       <li class="nav-item signup">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/sign-up" >Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  background-color:#ffffff;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.nav-item{
    margin:5px;
}

.signin, .signup {
    border:2px solid;

}

.signin {
    border-color:#232323 !important;
}

nav .nav-item ul li a.signin {
    color:#232323;
}

.signin:hover {
    background-color:#232323;
    color:#ffffff;
}

nav .nav-item ul li .signin a :hover {
    color:#ffffff;
}

.signup {
    background-color:#44A423;
    border-color:#44A423;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {

    font-size:23px;
    padding:10px 20px;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-item.signup .nav-link {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:23px;
}
```

How can I make that signup nav item's link color white? For complete example I will also share a link in the comment:

Comment: Here is the complete example:

https://codepen.io/artyombaykov/pen/eQGjZq?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

you can just add class text-white to the li tag like below

```
  <li class="nav-item signup text-white">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/sign-up" >Sign Up</a>
  </li>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. What if I want to add another color later?

Comment: you can add inline style or in the css file, for example  <li class="nav-item signup" style="color:blue;">

Answer (score 1):

Add it like this

```
.signup a {
  color: white;
}
```

*You need to add color on the anchor, instead of the li*

```css
section {
  background: #2193b0;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #6dd5ed, #2193b0);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6dd5ed, #2193b0);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  padding-top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  /* New code */
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 80px;
  margin-top: -80px;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.nav-item {
  margin: 5px;
}

.signin,
.signup {
  border: 2px solid;
}

.signin {
  border-color: #232323 !important;
}

nav .nav-item ul li a.signin {
  color: #232323;
}

.signin:hover {
  background-color: #232323;
  color: #ffffff;
}

nav .nav-item ul li .signin a :hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.signup {
  background-color: #44A423;
  border-color: #44A423;
}

.signup a {
  background-color: #44A423;
  border-color: #44A423;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  font-size: 23px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-item.signup .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.emp-profile {
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px
}

.profile-img {
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-img img {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-col h5 {
  color: #333;
}

.main-col h6 {
  color: green;
  margin-bottom: 30px
}

.row-details {
  margin-top: 30px
}

.profile-tab label {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.profile-tab p {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: green;
}

.img-content {
  margin: 30px 15px !important
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  bg-faded ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="../assets/images/close.png" class="img-fluid" style="width:50px; height:50px" alt="">
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Item 1</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item signin">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/sign-in">Sign in</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item signup">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" routerLink="/sign-up">Sign Up</a>
        </li>


      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="emp-profile justify-content-center">
      <form method="post">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="profile-img">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <div class="tab-content profile-tab" id="myTabContent">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 main-col col-sm-12  col-12 d-flex d-sm-block flex-column align-items-center">
                  <h5>
                    Kshiti Ghelani
                  </h5>
                  <h6>
                    24 Years Old
                  </h6>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6">
                  <a href="#" class="btn button-image closeButton btn-match float-right">Follow</a>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-6">
                  <a href="#" class="btn button-image closeButton btn-message">Message</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 d-flex">
                  <label>Username</label>
                  <p class="ml-auto">Kshiti123</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 d-flex">
                  <label>Profession</label>
                  <p class="ml-auto">Designer</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 d-flex">
                  <label>Gender</label>
                  <p class="ml-auto">Female</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 d-flex">
                  <label>Job Title</label>
                  <p class="ml-auto">UI Designer</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 d-flex">
                  <label>Country</label>
                  <p class="ml-auto">UK</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 d-flex">
                  <label>City</label>
                  <p class="ml-auto">Oxford</p>
                </div>
              </div>



            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-3 img-content'>
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-3 img-content'>
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-3 img-content'>
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tollit munere quo ne, timeam saperet ea mel. Ad vide essent dolores usu, ponderum salutatus ea duo, est alii commune ea. Pro euismod legimus detracto ad. Ei eius expetenda assueverit vis, cu duo sapientem temporibus,
              quo minim nostro ut.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no `.navbar-light` class in the html so you cannot get the css!

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {

    font-size:23px;
    padding:10px 20px;
}

.navbar-nav .signup .nav-link {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:23px;
}
```

**Hover-Example:**

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item .signup .nav-link:hover{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:23px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. For the hover should I just add :hover on your second css block?

Comment: And keep the selector-query simple... you only need ".signup .nav-link:hover" for example